# Spine.js clear model records on fetch

Tags: coffeescript, spine.js

There is `refresh` function in Spine.js which has this option:

```
You can pass the option {clear: true} to wipe all the existing records.
```

but let's say i'm implementing pagination and want all records be cleared on every fetch, because now when i fetch next page,
then new records are just appended to current recordset and page bloats, wchich is undesirable.
Unfortunately `fetch` has no such useful option. So is it possible to achieve similar functionality for `fetch` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I would take is to override the default fetch by adding your custom fetch method on your model